# Can I daisy chain multiple displays with Thunderbolt?

Tags: thunderbolt, displayport, compatibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Thunderbolt support chaining multiple monitors to a MacBook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9087/does-thunderbolt-support-chaining-multiple-monitors-to-a-macbook-pro)

This question is a follow up to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9087/does-thunderbolt-support-chaining-multiple-monitors) I found on this site.

If I have a monitor that supports DisplayPort, will it be possible (with a Mini Display Port to DisplayPort cable) to have my monitor ([Dell U2711](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&cs=04&l=en&s=bsd&sku=224-8284&redirect=1)) at the end of a Thunderbolt daisy chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the port on the MacBook Pro is both a DisplayPort and a Thunderbolt port. The limitation, as already explained in the other question, is only relevant to DisplayPort, which has to be the last device in the chain, if daisy chained.

So in short, and in theory, it should work. According to the [Thunderbolt](http://www.apple.com/thunderbolt/) page, you can plug in any adapter for DisplayPort and it should work, as long as the device also supports it.

The only time this gets really complex, is when you need to both power the device and use it using just the one port. If the device has external power, it shouldn't cause any major problems daisy chaining, however, the DisplayPort device still needs the last device in the chain. Simply because it cannot transfer data at the speed and rate the Thunderbolt can.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's just the info I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Only if you don't have a Thunderbolt display in the chain.  [According to Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4885), you can daisy-chain two Thunderbolt displays on compatible systems, but not non-Thunderbolt displays (such as the LED Cinema Display, which uses Mini DisplayPort, or others via a Mini DisplayPort adapter).

[Otherwise, it works fine](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4744).