# Can I use two non-Thunderbolt displays on a MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have been told that the only way to connect more than one external display to a MacBook Air was to buy Apple's Thunderbolt monitor and daisy chain.

Mavericks promises better support for external displays. Is it now possible to run two non-Thunderbolt monitors from a mid-2013 MacBook Air or is this still impossible?

Comment: Note that [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41446/how-to-connect-multiple-monitors-to-a-macbook-air?rq=1) is similar but refers to older hardware and software.

Comment: [this  Matrox adapter](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital_se/?productTabs=1) is a partial solution, but tricks the mac into thinking the two monitors are one super-wide display. It would be nice to have a solution that recognizes that the two displays are in fact two displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect two monitors to a 2013 Macbook Air by connecting one to the Mini DisplayPort, and one to the USB port via this USB - DVI adapter:

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0086359SG/ref=oh_details_o00_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0086359SG)

With the computer open, this gives you up to three screens. The USB connected screen is minimally laggy - fine for work, but probably not good for games or video.

Comment: on Marvicks I have this issue when the displayLink (USB to dvi adapter) is connected that sometimes the whole machine would just crash and restart it self. Anyone else having this issue?

Comment: I've had this same setup and it works, however the system tends to crash when using expose or mission control.

Comment: sadly, these DisplayLink adapters are still this buggy. when you use Mission Control, your computer crashes and logs you out. not a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

The changes in Mavericks make it possible to connect a DisplayPort monitor to your MBA and also use an Apple TV as an external display - I've just confirmed it on my setup - but that is pretty slow over wifi.

The issues with connecting monitors to the MBA are in hardware, not software. For example, the reason why you cannot connect a DisplayPort adapter to the Apple Thunderbolt Display is because the monitor itself uses the DisplayPort channel:

http://www.anandtech.com/show/4832/the-apple-thunderbolt-display-review/8

Connecting two displays to the MBA requires two thunderbolt devices.

The first device can be either the Apple TB display or one of the Thunderbolt docks with a DVI / HDMI connector. Both of these options use the DisplayPort channel, so connecting a DisplayPort monitor to them won't work.

This is where the second Thunderbolt device comes in (a hard disk or other device with two TB ports for pass-through). This acts as a man-in-the-middle and can extract a second DisplayPort signal.

So your setup will look like this:

`<Air> -- <TB dock/display> -- <TB drive> -- <DisplayPort monitor>`

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to daisy chain two external monitors.

This [KB-article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219?viewlocale=en_US#minimul) lists the models that support up to 2 displays through one Thunderbolt port.

- **MacBook Air (Mid 2012 and later)**
- MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012 and later)
- MacBook Pro (15-inch and 17-inch, Early 2011 and later)
- iMac (Mid 2011 and later)
- Mac Mini (Mid 2011 and later)

Comment: The question was about using non-thunderbolt displays.

Comment: You can use two thunderbolt docks. The original page is visible on https://web.archive.org/web/20151220213512/https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204154

Comment: I just one to confirm that using two Belkin thunderbolt 2 docks connected in daisy chain, I'm able to use tow screens at the same time with no problem, with my Early-2015 macbook air. Only viable thanks to 2nd hand docks getting cheaper :P

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Thunderbolt to HDMI then a HDMI splitter and I know there's a program to make your MacBook think you are using one big display.

Comment: Won't the splitter mirror the displays, as the Macbook can't differentiate between the two?