# Dual monitor for 2.2GHz MacBook Pro (MD318LL/A) Late 2011 MBP

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi

I was wondering is it possible to have 2 external 1080P monitors attached to my MBP?

My machine have a Thunderbolt port.

The monitors have HDMI, VGA, and DVI. (No thunderbolt display port sadly.)

Is it possible to connect 2 external monitors to the MBP without using an USB video card? I am okay with using the MBP in clamshell mode. On this stackexchange there are methods that involves Thunderbolt -> 2 DVI/HDMI adapter, would this allow me to have 2 separate desktops?

Thanks

Comment: you could use a hdmi splitter but then both monitors would show the same!

Answer (score 1):

Never tried with Thunderbolt splitting, but regularly run with multiple monitors. Using other methods.

Assume you meant to ad this link to question?

[How to connect two non-Thunderbolt displays to the Macbook Pro 2011 via Thunderbolt?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46104/how-to-connect-two-non-thunderbolt-displays-to-the-macbook-pro-2011-via-thunderb)

From Documentation looks like your Mac only has one Thunderbolt port that also doubles as the display out.   Officially it supports 2 Displays per Thunderbolt port

Nothing that I can see in Apple Store but Found something that should work.   Note I do not have personal experience with this product.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Zotac-ZT-MDP2HD-Mini-Dual-Cable/dp/B005FSHHHG/ref=sr_1_1?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1349690750&sr=1-1