# Can I use two 27" Cinema Displays from a 15" MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, cinema-display, thunderbolt-display

I am interested in purchasing a MacBook Pro and running multiple monitors when I am at my desk. Ideally, I'd like to run two 27" Cinema Displays when I am working at my desk, but would be okay with two smaller monitors.

Is this configuration possible? Does it require a combination of both Thunderbolt and DVI connectors?

<sub>I am aware that there is a similar question about [utilizing multiple monitors when using the MacBook Air](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/18017/1298), but didn't feel like it gave enough detail about MacBook Pros.</sub>

Comment: How is your situation different http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9087/does-thunderbolt-support-chaining-multiple-monitors-to-a-macbook-pro ? It's OK to have several very close questions even if the answers to all end up being identical. However, adding details to each question to make them unique is best for the site in the long run. Are you looking for a general answer or one for a specific model of MacBook Pro for example. +1 for linking to a similar question and searching for a dupe first!

Comment: @bmike it doesn't. My searching netted the aforementioned question about the [MacBook Airs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/18017/1298), but I didn't find the one you reference. Looking at the two the only real difference is the question about connecting via both Thunderbolt and DVI, but closing this as an exact duplicate wouldn't hurt my feelings. :) Thanks for pointing out the other question.

Comment: I'll leave it up to you - unless people flag it, I see no reason to delete things - the DVI could be meaningful to someone and they come along and improve things later if we learn more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about a Thunderbolt equipped 15-inch MacBook Pro then **yes** according to this:

[Apple Thunderbolt Display (27-inch): Connection options for Thunderbolt Macs](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4885)

Interestingly you can also drive two from a 13-inch MacBook Pro, it will disable the built in display.

Answer (score 1):

[Yes, you can](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42565/dongles-to-connect-2-monitors-to-a-13-mid-2010-macbook-pro-mini-displayport/42641#42641).  You'll need a Matrox DualHead2Go DP and 2 [DisplayPort to Mini DisplayPort](http://www.universalmania.net/index.do?type=productDetail&productId=1016700906&categoryId=10009) adapters.

Answer (score 1):

I have a mid 2011 15" MBP, 2.3 GHz i7, 16Gb RAM. This model is equipped with one thunderbolt port; I have two 27" Thunderbolt displays daisy chained to the port with full resolution and no issues.

There is one item of concern however...I feel this at the edge of what my computer can handle.  My system resources are not taxed but my fans are on pretty high to accommodate the increased strain on my GPU...I suspect anyway.

I used @Robins link and verified my model is capable of running two displays(see item 14 in the post)...[14. How many Apple Thunderbolt Displays can I use with my Mac in OS X?](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US#dispnum).

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the OP question, which is about "Cinema" displays.