# Dongles to connect 2 monitors to a 13" mid-2010 MacBook Pro (mini DisplayPort)?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport

I won't be using the integrated display. Right now, one external monitor is connected through a mini DisplayPort to VGA adaptor. How should I connect a second?

Answer (score 6):

Another option to to use a display multiplexer, like the [Matrox DualHead2Go DP](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/?productTabs=1).  This will have much better performance (frame rate / snappiness) than the USB solution, at about 4X the price.  It's best with matched dual external displays - or triple; there's also a 3-monitor solution.  I haven't used one personally, but have recommended it to clients with success.  [The reviews are quite good.](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/press/editorial/dualhead2go/reviews_awards/)

Answer (score 4):

An option for this MacBook Pro is to add a USB Video adapter to get that 2nd external monitor. They are available in a wide range of resolutions and connectivity. Not sure which is the best one to buy but here is an example of a [USB 2.0 to DVI Display Adapter](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=101&cp_id=10114&cs_id=1011403&p_id=6040&seq=1&format=2).

[image: USB to DVI adapter Example]

Comment: Remember that these solutions are not good at graphics: you'll be able to use Excel or text editors but you won't be playing games.

Comment: I agree! I just bought a DisplayLink adapter and tested it today... It's unusable to me :( I wish I had known about this earlier