# Target Display Mode Question

Tags: display, imac, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I have a Mac book pro (13 inch late 2013) and I have an old iMac (27 inch mid 2010).

I checked on apple website and it says that the 27 inch Mid 2010 model does support target display mode

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592

It says that target display mode is supported but I need a "mini display to mini display cable"

but when I look at my MBP, it does have any mini display port. it has only 2 thunderbolt ports.

So will I be able to use the old iMac as a external display?

Comment: [Andrew Cassell's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9087/does-thunderbolt-support-chaining-multiple-monitors-to-a-macbook-pro/18023#18023) even has a nice image of what you want to do. I realize you only have one iMac and the image shows two iMacs.

Comment: Thunderbolt is a multiplexing of several signals - PCIe, USB, and DisplayPort.  So, your TB port is also a DisplayPort port.